# No USB3 after cloning Samsung to Samsung

Tags: clone

I have tried many times to clone my new Samsung something to another Samsung something for a backup but every time I end up with a drive that refuses to recognize my USB3 ports.  All other devices like mouse and keyboard work fine. I am using a Gigabyte Z97X-UD5H board with Intel i7-4790K 4 GHz. 32 Gigs DDR3 Crucial PC3 10600, and a pair of Samsung 850 EVO 500GB ssd. The non working USB indication in device manager allows me to remove and try to update drivers but nothing helps. I can not see a thumb drive or External SSD connected to the USB3 ports.

I have tried various clone applications and even tried moving the System SSD to another computer along with  the destination SSD but I get the same problem. The clone works fine otherwise but no USB3.

I have been successful when I used the Crucial brand on same system but not the Samsung.

I am at a total loss as to what to do next.

Any suggestions  will be welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

Remove Samsung Magician Software before or after cloning if the destination drive is not Samsung.